# Long running operations timeout/TTL in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-functions

How long will Google cloud hold details on long-running operations?

By referring google cloud speech client, for an asynchronous speech transcription, audio file should be uploaded to Google cloud storage and storage details should be sent for transcription. Google cloud will respond with a google cloud [long operation resource](https://cloud.google.com/service-management/reference/rest/v1/operations)

To query the status of operations, we can use HTTP GET but how long will Google cloud store the operation details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requests that use Streaming and Synchronous Speech Recognition with the Cloud Speech API are not persisted at all.

This is different for Asynchronous Speech Recognition requests, which are kept for up to 5 days to give customers the chance to fetch them (using the [`operations.get` method from the API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1/operations/get)) during that period of time. After that time, the operations are deleted and do not persist.

Also, if you have any other doubt regarding the agreed terms to how the Google Cloud Platform handles data processing, you may be interested in this documentation page about the [Data Processing and Security Terms](https://cloud.google.com/terms/data-processing-terms).

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!